# Foreign key id and description on SaveChanges() overide - Entity Framework

Tags: .net, entity-framework

I have a requirement to add a generic audit log for each entity, therefore I have overridden the `SaveChanges()` method in the `DbContext` class and able to create the logs.

My issue is with the foreign keys, I need to get the text value of the foreign key instead of the id for the entities.

Thanks in advance

RJ

here is the code

```
if (dbEntry.State == System.Data.EntityState.Modified)
{
if (!object.Equals(dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(propertyName), dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName)))
{
var oldvalue = dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(propertyName) != null ? dbEntry.GetDatabaseValues().GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString() : "";
var newvalue = dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName) != null ? dbEntry.CurrentValues.GetValue<object>(propertyName).ToString() : "";
Auidlog += displayName + ": Changed from - " + oldvalue + " To - " + newvalue + " ";
}
}
```

in the oldvalue/newvalue  variable return only the foreign key id, I need the description for that

Comment: the code so far ?  A little more info would help. Not clear what you are trying to do and what you dont understand how to do.

Comment: Ok so you understand how to use dbEntry.CurrentValues and dbEntityEntry.OriginalValues.Note GetDbValues goes back to Db.Different to originalValue check. Anyway so you know what has changed. So what has that to do with foreign keys ? You want to query the EF model ?

Comment: Which description.  You have the propertyName. So which text do you refer to ?

Comment: thank you phil for you reply, what i want is, suppose in my entity (Class) I have a foreign key relation with another entity(student), (like studentId PK, studentName) in the class table i will store only the studentid, the GetDatabaseValues/OriginalValues will give me only the id, but I want the "StudentName" from the other entity, to create the audit log.

Answer (score 0):

You can access the metadata of the model using:

```
   ObjectContext objContext = ((IObjectContextAdapter)context).ObjectContext;
   MetadataWorkspace workspace = objContext.MetadataWorkspace;
   IEnumerable<EntityType> managedTypes = workspace.GetItems<EntityType>(DataSpace.OSpace);
```

The DataSpace.xxxx has other enums exposing different views of the metaData. So check them all out.

But how do you plan to access the "text" field of the Primary table.
Find the a string ? find a property that contains the term Name or text ?
Perhaps you can implement an interface on EVERY primary table. Or add an attribute to the main text field of the table.

That seems more like the outstanding challenge.